# Can not set state from graphql query until page refresh React/ GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a component which queries for a currently authed user via `graphQl` and `useQuery` hook

```
const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useAppContext()
  const { data: authedUserData, error } = useQuery(GET_AUTHED_USER);

  console.log('authed user', authedUserData?.getAuthedUser) // logs authed user
  console.log('state', state) // logs null

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authedUserData?.getAuthedUser) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        currentUser: authedUserData.getAuthedUser,
        isAuthed: true
      });
    }
  }, [])


  if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <Posts data={data} header={<NavHeader />} />
  )
}
```

I am then trying to set whatever comes back from `GET_AUTHED_USER` into a piece of global state, I see in the logs `authedUserData.getAuthedUser` does log my user but `state` logs as null until I refresh the page. Placing any dependency inside the `useEffect` will trigger an infinite loop. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using an empty array as your `useEffect` dependency list tells React that you only want this function to be run once, after [initial render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). By the time your GraphQL result has come back, you've missed that.

You need to "listen" to the `authedUserData`, and act once it's no longer `undefined`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (authedUserData?.getAuthedUser) {
      setState({
        ...state,
        currentUser: authedUserData.getAuthedUser,
        isAuthed: true
      });
    }
  }, [authedUserData])
```

Comment: adding ```authedUserData``` in the dependency array resulted in an infinite render loop